# How to override resource in ThemeDictionary using code (UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I would like to have the equivalent of the XAML, but in C# code:

```
<Application.Resources>

    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumLowBrush" Color="White" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush" Color="White" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>

    </ResourceDictionary>

</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your Application `OnLaunched` method:

```
ResourceDictionary lightTheme = new ResourceDictionary();
lightTheme["SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumLowBrush"] = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.White);
lightTheme["SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush"] = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.White);
App.Current.Resources.ThemeDictionaries.Add("Light", lightTheme);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
Brush SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
Brush SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
```

Then you could use it like this to set the colour of a button

```
myButton.Background = SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush;
```

If, as your comment suggests you want to change the colour on mouse hover you need to capture the mousehover event and then you could change the colour to one of your named styles. For example to change the button colour on mousehover you could do this

```
private void myButton_MouseHover(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{
    myButton.Background = SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to set the background, but the Brush of the Mouse Hover.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: Well, the whole story is that I want to override those Theme Resources to make modify the color of Buttons when the mouse hovers over them. If you put the XAML in my question and a Button in a Page, you will see the result.